# jquery validation not working in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on Jquery validation,I have three fileds in my form (title,file,ckeditor) but
my ckeditor validation not working for me , i tried with following code but validation working except "ckeditor",where
i am wrong ? Thanks in advance

```
<form name="addblog" id="addblog" method="POST">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
 <input class="form-control validate[required]" type="file" id="file" name="file" required>
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1" name="editor1" id="editor1" required></textarea>
</form>
```

Here is my script code

```
<script>
$().ready(function() {
$("#addblog").validate({
            rules: {
                    file: {
                    required: true
                    },
                    'editor1': {
                    required: true
                    }
            },
            messages: {
        file: {
                     required: "Please enter your image"
                 }
                },
        });
});
</script>
```